# Prolog, X before Y in a List

Tags: list, prolog

I am having trouble understanding prolog, I have to find if X is before Y in a list.

so I have a base case with an empty list

```
before(X, Y, [ ]).
```

Now I know that I want to check the index of X and the index of Y in List and if `indexX < indexY` I want to have a success.

Could someone explain a simple way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the Prolog documentation for predicates pertaining to lists? In particular, there are predicates involving indices. Also, you do not have to use indices here. A better approach would be to recursively look for `X`, then check if `Y` is a member of the rest of the list. Or you can do this with a DCG.

Comment: Say the list does not contain X or Y, should the predicate then succeed? Technically speaking in a list not containing X nor Y, you could say X is located before the Y.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) to locate X and the remaining list after it, then locate Y.

```
before(X, Y, L):-
  append(_, [X|Tail], L),
  append(_, [Y|_], Tail).
```

Comment: That's an interesting use of `append/3` ;).

Comment: s(X): for using `append/3` which is widely available and part of the Prolog prologue (cf. https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue).

Answer (score 3):

Using a DCG, it would look like this (using a predicate named `...` for notational/visual convenience):

```
before(X, Y) --> ..., [X], ..., [Y], ... .
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

| ?- phrase(before(X, Y), [a,b,c]).

X = a
Y = b ? ;

X = a
Y = c ? ;

X = b
Y = c ? ;

(1 ms) no
```

And you can wrap it in a predicate, if you wish:

```
before(X, Y, L) :- phrase(before(X, Y), L).
```

---

As @CapelliC points out, the above predicate succeeds if there is *at least one case* in the list in which `X` comes before `Y`. However, if the definition is, *`X` is seen before `Y` in the list*, then an alternative DCG implementation could be:

```
before(X, Y) --> anything_but(Y), [X], ..., [Y], ... .

anything_but(_) --> [].
anything_but(Y) --> [X], { dif(X, Y) }, anything_but(Y).

... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .
```

Which results in:

```
| ?-  phrase(before(X,Y), [b,a,b]).

X = b
Y = b ? a

X = a
Y = b

no
```

Comment: the question is fairly ambigous, nevertheless I think this should not succeed: `?- phrase(before(a,b),[b,a,b]).
true` -. The same, of course, for @gusbro answer.

Comment: @CapelliC well, since `a` does occur before `b` in some part of the sequence, I believe it *should* succeed. I think that's the more logical interpretation. The query is about whether *`X` is before `Y`*, which would be true in at least one case, not whether *`X` is always before `Y`*,  or *`X` is never after `Y`*, which would fail. :)

Comment: @repeat have you considered a career as a foreign diplomat? ;)

Comment: @CapelliC what about `phrase(before(a,b), [a,b,a])`? In your opinion, should it succeed or fail? It would succeed in all three of the proposed answers.

Comment: @CapelliC, I'm definitely seeing your point now, and I added an alternative solution per that definition.

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, list processing is in most cases done without using indices: you use recursion, and you try to formulate it as a logical expression. If you don't want to use built-ins, you can write:

```
before(X,Y,[X|T]) :-
    !,
    contains(Y,T).
before(X,Y,[_|T]) :-
    before(X,Y,T).

contains(Y,[Y|_]) :-
    !.
contains(Y,[_|T]) :-
    contains(Y,T).
```

The code makes use of a defined `contains/2` predicate that checks whether the list `L` contains `Y`. Now the `before/2` predicate contains two clauses. The first clause specifies that the first element of the list is `X`, in that case, we only need to check whether the remainder of the list contains an `Y`. In case the first element of the list is not an `X`, the list is shifted one further, and by using recursion, we try to find a location where there is an `X`.

Note that this predicate **requires that both `X` and `Y` are elements of the list**. Furthermore there can be multiple `X` and `Y`s. So `before(a,b,[b,a,a,b])` will succeed, simple because there is an `a` and a `b` such that the `a` is before the `b`.

**EDIT**

If you want to use the predicate in a reversed way (*query fashion*), you should omit the cuts:

```
before(X,Y,[X|T]) :-
    contains(Y,T).
before(X,Y,[_|T]) :-
    before(X,Y,T).

contains(Y,[Y|_]).
contains(Y,[_|T]) :-
    contains(Y,T).
```

Then you can query like:

```
?- before(X,Y,[a,b,c]).
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = a,
Y = c ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
false.
```

Comment: Why the cuts? With the cuts, you don't get all of the solutions to `before(X, Y, [a,b,c])`.

Comment: The cuts are indeed optional and indeed can better be omitted if you want to use the predicate in query fashion. Will update the answer.

Comment: Isn't any call to a predicate a *query*? :) The cuts remove the relational aspect of the query and cause it to terminate early, so the variety of queries it supports is reduced. For example, a perfectly good query should be: `before(X, c, [a,b,c]).` and the query should yield the correct results: `X = a` and `X = b`. With the cuts, it's not correct.

Comment: @lurker: yes, that was more or less the point I was making. Rereading the comment, translating the ideas from Dutch to English, some infomation went missing.

Comment: I see that it works but I am not sure how you can think in a way which is not imperative. Looking at your answer it makes sense, given a list with a head and a tail, is Y in the tail. If not is x before Y in the tail. Is that the whole of it?

Comment: Why define `contains/2` when you could use `member/2`? `member/2` is offered by most Prolog processors and it is part of the Prolog prologue (cf. https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue).

Comment: @MichaelMiner - In what way is the solution without the cuts imperative?

Comment: @lurker, not saying it is, I'm asking how can one think in a non imperative way. I'm surprised how easy this is for some.

Comment: @MichaelMiner oh I see what you mean. You have to work a few problems and you get used to thinking that way. Think of these relations as *such and such is true if this and that...* (declarative). It helps to express them that way, rather than expressing them as *do this and do that* (imperative).

Comment: @repeat: the idea is to show an implementation without using *any* builtin predicates. I know that `member/2` and `append/3` can be useful here, and indeed one should use these for production code, but in order to understand what happens behind the curtains, it is probably better to show some implementation work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that uses no built-in predicates whatsoever.

It helps if you re-cast the problem in somewhat more generic terms.

A common prolog idiom is a public predicate that invokes a worker predicate that does all the work. Often, the worker predicate will carry additional variable that maintain state. In this case, we don't need to maintain state, but it simplifies things if we make the actual solution more generic: instead of defining the problem in terms of `X` and `Y`, redefineit in terms of a list of arbitrary length, defining the order in which things must be found in the target list.

Then, it's simply a matter of recursing down both lists in parallel to determine if the precedence constraints are satisfied. The generic solution (which will work for a list containing an arbitrary number of constraints) has 3 cases:

> - The constraint list is empty: **Success!**
> - The head of the constraint list unifies with the head of the list being
>     tested. That indicates that a constraint has been satisfied. Remove both the
>     constraint and the item it just matched (the head of the list being tested)
>     and recurse down.
> - Finally, just remove the head of the list being tested and recurse down.

The solution looks like this:

```
x_before_y( X , Y, Zs ) :- satisfies_constraints( [X,Y] , Zs ) .

satisfies_constraints( []     , _      ) .
satisfies_constraints( [C|Cs] , [C|Xs] ) :- satisfies_constraints(Cs,Xs) .
satisfies_constraints( Cs     , [_|Xs] ) :- satisfies_constraints(Cs,Xs) .
```

On backtracking, this will find all possible solutions. If that's not desirable, a cut in the 2nd clause will eliminate the choice points:

```
satisfies_constraints( []     , _      ) .
satisfies_constraints( [C|Cs] , [C|Xs] ) :- !, satisfies_constraints(Cs,Xs) .
satisfies_constraints( Cs     , [_|Xs] ) :-    satisfies_constraints(Cs,Xs) .
```

As will introducing a test for non-unifiability in the 3rd clause:

```
satisfies_constraints( []     , _      ) .
satisfies_constraints( [C|Cs] , [C|Xs] ) :- satisfies_constraints(Cs,Xs) .
satisfies_constraints( [C|Cs] , [X|Xs] ) :-
  C \= X ,
  satisfies_constraints([C|Cs],Xs)
  .
```