# Prolog, X element before element Y on list

Tags: prolog

I am going to write predicate which is true iff only and only when element `X` occurs before `Y` on list `L`

```
before(L, X, Y) :-
    nth1(PX, L, X),
    nth1(PY, L, Y),
    PX < PY.
```

Above, you can see my solution. What do you think about it ?

When it comes to my specific question:
My predicate returns true when there is exists at least one pair that `Y` followed `X`.   How to define predicate such that it is true for each pair ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [same problem previously asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633942/prolog-x-before-y-in-a-list/33635213#33635213). One issue I see with your solution is that you are thinking about Prolog imperatively. That is, you're asking yourself "what do I tell Prolog to do to this information to get the results I want" rather than thinking relationally.

Comment: So, how to think ? Logically ?  It is not such easy

Comment: I agree, if you're used to programming imperatively, it's hard to think relationally. It takes some practice. Instead of thinking about telling the computer what to do to get to the answer, you want to describe the relationship between the variables. See the question and solutions I linked as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition should hold for *all* pairs, the condition should hold for at least one pair, while its converse shouldn't be true for *any* pair.

I took the liberty of renaming your `before/3` to `beforeSome/3`.

```
beforeSome(L, X, Y) :-
    nth1(PX, L, X),
    nth1(PY, L, Y),
    PX < PY.

beforeAll(L, X, Y) :-
    beforeSome(X,Y),
    not(beforeSome(L, Y, X)).
```

Which yields the desired results:

```
?- beforeAll([1,2,3,1,4,5], 1, 4).
true.

?- beforeAll([1,2,3,1,4,5], 1, 2).
false.
```

---

Please note that your use of `nth1/3` precludes it being used with uninstantiated variables. In other words, `beforeAll([1,2,3,1,4,5], X, Y).` is `false`.

A better implementation of `beforeSome/3` would be something like

```
beforeSome([X|T], X, Y) :-
    member(Y, T).

beforeSome([_|T], X, Y) :-
    beforeSome(T, X, Y).

% no change needed, but repeated here for completeness' sake
beforeAll(L, X, Y) :-
    beforeSome(X,Y),
    not(beforeSome(L, Y, X)).
```

Comment: Thanks for your warning at the bottom your post.  It seems to be worth to think about it.  Can you see other way ? After all,  `beforeAll([1,2,3,1,4,5], X, Y)` (`X` and `Y` is uninstantiated) always will be `false`.  PS: My task tell that only list is instantiated always. However, I was aware of it - after all unistantiated `X` or `Y` always return false.

Comment: You could use `beforeSome([X|T], X, Y) :- member(Y, T). beforeSome([H|T], X, Y) :-  dif(H,X), beforeSome(T, X, Y).` for `beforeSome/3`, but the `not/1` precludes generation. So that would need another definition as well.

Comment: Tell me please, how to think about predicates in order to finding solution as your ? I have often problem that my solution is not **general**

Comment: This allows elements that are not in the list to succeed, so for example, this succeeds: `beforeAll([1,2,3,4,5,6], 9, 8).`

Comment: @lurker agreed. Checking for membership first would solve that.

Answer (score 4):

The solution you show works for the "if one exists" case, but is somewhat imperative in nature. That is, it's a little bit like a C program translated to Prolog. Imperative means you are telling the computer, using the programming language, what steps to execute in order to achieve your results.

To be more declarative or relational, your "exists" solution could be expressed nicely as a DCG:

```
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

before(X, Y) --> ... , [X], ... , [Y], ... .
```

(NOTE: You can in Prolog have a predicate named `...`, which is shown here.) This describes the relationship of `X` and `Y` in the list. It does not describe steps to execute, but instead describes the relationship of `X` and `Y` in a sequence. This solution has been shown [before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633942/prolog-x-before-y-in-a-list).

Following this approach (where we describe the relationship of `X` and `Y`), one way (not necessarily the only way) to express that all the `X` precede all the `Y` would be:

```
before_all(X, Y) -->
    { dif(X,Y) },
    any_sequence_but(Y), [X], any_sequence_but(Y), [Y], any_sequence_but(X).

any_sequence_but(_) --> [].
any_sequence_but(Y) --> [X], { dif(X,Y) }, any_sequence_but(Y).
```

Which yields a solution like this:

```
?- phrase(before_all(X,Y), [b,a,b,c,a,b,d]).
X = b,
Y = d ;
X = a,
Y = d ;
X = b,
Y = d ;
X = c,
Y = d ;
X = a,
Y = d ;
X = b,
Y = d ;
false.

?-
```

Comment: Is `anything` a good name for a sequence? Just wondering.

Comment: @false probably not the best choice.... but something to ponder.

Comment: anysequence, any**s**

Comment: @false or more specifically in my case, `any_sequence_excluding`.

Comment: I prefer "but" over "excluding". "But" is not a verb. So it does not have that operational connotation that actually someone did exclude something.

Comment: @false excellent. And "but" is shorter which is an extra bonus.